# Accessing offsetHeight and offsetWidth in Polymer

Tags: html, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a script I would like to run as soon as the page loads. However, this script is based on the offsetHeight and offsetWidth properties of an element. I've tried calling the script inside both the "ready" and "attached" functions, but neither of those seem to be run at a time when offsetHeight and Width have been set. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

By default, Polymer element display as `inline`. If you have children that display as `block` inside your element, your element will have an offsetWidth and offsetHeight of 0. You can check this with the dev tools when your app has fully loaded. So it's not a lifecycle issue, these values will be zero any time you check. To enforce a height and a width you can change the display property of your element to `display: block`. Then, checking the `offsetWidth` in the `attached` callback should work.